# Take a list/array of names and count the number of times each unique name is listed

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

The input for this code is:

```
"John, Mary, Joe, John, John, John, Mary, Mary, Steve."
```

My goal is to print out:

> "(Name) got (# of votes) votes."

Ending with a statement of the winner.

I can't seem to debug my code though. This is my code:

```
static void popularity_contest(List<String> name_list) {

    largest_count = "";
    largest_count = 0;
    int n = name_list.size();
    int count = 1;
    int y = sorted(name_list);
      for(i=1; i<name_list.length; i++){
          if (n[i] == n[i-1]){
              count += 1;
          }
              else
              {
                  name = n[i-1];
                  System.out.println(n[i-1] + " got " + str.length(count) + " votes.");
                  if (count > largest_count)
                  {
                          largest_count = count;
                          largest_name = name;
                          count = 1;
                   }
        System.out.println(str.length(y)-1 + " got " + str.length(count) + " votes.");
        name = str.length(y)-1;           
      }
          if (count > largest_count)
          {
              largest_count = count;
              largest_name = name;
            System.out.print(largest_name + " Wins!");
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to debug my code"? What have you tried? What is your work environment?

Comment: _I can't seem to debug my code_ Why not?

Comment: You mean you can't even compile your code, right?

Comment: You need 2 loops atleast to compare the names every time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use Java 8, this can be done very easily with streams and `Collectors.groupingBy()` :

```
Map<String, Long> collect = name_list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                 Collectors.counting()));
```

You will get a `Map<String, Long>`  with key representing the name, and value representing the number of times it repeats. Example :

```
{Tom=2, Timmy=1, Elena=1}
```

Although this might be too advanced as you are new to java.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by @SchiduLuca but I thought I would present a solution not using streams. (In my code there might be a draw between two or more winners)

```
static void popularity_contest(List<String> name_list) {

  Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

  for (String name : name_list) {
    Integer count = result.get(name);
    if (count == null) {
      count = new Integer(1);
      result.put(name, count);
    } else {
      result.put(name, count + 1);
    } 
  }

  //Print result and look for max # votes
  Integer maxVotes = new Integer(0);

  for (Entry<String, Integer> contestant : result.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s got %d votes", contestant.getKey(), contestant.getValue().intValue()));
    if (contestant.getValue() > maxVotes) {
      maxVotes = contestant.getValue();
    }
  }

  //Print all winners
  System.out.println("*** Winner(s) ***");
  for (Entry<String, Integer> contestant : result.entrySet()) {        
    if (contestant.getValue() == maxVotes) {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s got %d votes and is a winner", contestant.getKey(), contestant.getValue().intValue()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest error lies in your comparison of the names. You are using == to compare strings when you need to use the method equals() or equalsIgnoreCase(). Finally you can just use your list you're given and use the get() method when accessing the element at a particular index.

```
if (name_list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(name_list.get(i-1))
{
    count += 1;
}
```